# ANT returning error code 139 when running via jenkins

Tags: ant, jenkins

After success execution of php unit tests, there is 139 code returned with stack trace:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/jenkins/workspace/phpUnit/tests/build.xml:25: exec returned: 139
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:636)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:662)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:487)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
```

Tests results indicates that everything is fine (all tests passed), bun because of this error code jenkins marks build as failure.

Answer (score 4):

found following explanation: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/omnetpp/_zonGWenUqg/pdTs1MPxcDAJ

and here the text:

> Unix systems return errono 128+signal when a signal received. 128 + 11
>   = 139 . SIgnal 11 is SIGSEV (i.e. segmentation violation). = There is a memory access bug in your C++ code

Answer (score 0):

This helped me immediately (thanks to [David Fuhr](http://www.mageblog.de/de/blog/2013/04/02/segfault-bei-phpunit-vermeiden/))

```
protected function setUp()
{
    gc_collect_cycles();
    gc_disable();

    parent::setUp();
}

protected function tearDown()
{
    parent::tearDown();

    gc_enable();
}
```